# ExtJS 6.2 : creating a custom filter for a gridcolumn

Tags: extjs, filter, grid, extjs6

I'd like to create a custom filter for my gridcolumn.

I tried this:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.grid.filters.filter.Float', {
  extend : 'Ext.grid.filters.filter.Number',
  alias  : ['grid.filter.float'],

  type : 'float',

  config : {
    serializer : function (f) {
      return {
        type     : 'float',
        value    : f.value,
        property : f.property,
        operator : f.operator
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Then I tried to use the filter in my gridcolumn:

```
   {
      header     : 'Foo',
      dataIndex  : 'bar',
      filterable : true,
      filter     : {
        type : 'float'
      }
    }
```

How do I create, add or register filters to the [gridfilter](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.filters.Filters.html)-plugin in my application? I really don't get it.

Thanks in advance

Solution:

We used the createFilter-function in [Ext.grid.filters.filter.Base](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.filters.filter.Base.html) to create and use the filter:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.foo.bar.FloatFilter', {
  extend : 'Ext.grid.filters.filter.Number',
  alias  : 'grid.filter.float',

  createFilter : function (config, key) {
    config.type = 'float';
    return this.callParent(arguments);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add new filter type you have to define new class, extended from [Ext.grid.filters.filter.Base](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.filters.filter.Base.html) or its descendant (just like you did it).

Check this [simple example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mr0).

Also, you can check existing filters code to know how you can add custom menu or filter rules, for example [Ext.grid.filters.filter.String](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/String.js-1.html#Ext.grid.filters.filter.String) based onf [Ext.grid.filters.filter.SingleFilter](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/SingleFilter.js.html#Ext.grid.filters.filter.SingleFilter).

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much. So the only mistake I did, was I specified the wrong namespace? Do I really have to define a class in the ext-namespace to make it work? Is there no way to create a filter in my own structure/namespace and add it manually to the plugin?

Comment: I think you can, but you have to override plugin code to accept class / class name, not just type string. Actually, application name (Myapp) is namespace for your views, controllers models and stores, while plugin use  Ext global object.

Comment: We found a solution for this. You can use the createFilter-Function in [Ext.grid.filters.filter.Base](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.filters.filter.Base.html) which is not listed in their documentation, but you can create a filter which is used by the plugin. I'll update my question soon.